# How do I push items to a Stack<T> after creating a Stack<T> instance in code?

Tags: c#, createinstance

I am creating a `Stack<T>` where I have the type of the `Stack` in a variable. After I have created the `Stack<T>`, I am wanting to push items to the `Stack`. How can I access the `Push` method?

Here is my code:

```
var itemType = GetIEnumerableItemType(type);
var stackType = typeof(Stack<>);
var constructedStackType = stackType.MakeGenericType(itemType);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedStackType);
```

**EDIT**

Here is some code that I have tried that works with a `List<T>`:

```
var itemType = GetIEnumerableItemType(type);
var listType = typeof(List<>);
var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(itemType);
var instance = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);
//instance.Add("example item");
```

Thank you

Comment: If you want to "push" the items from the enumerable you're seemingly using, why not just pass it to the `Stack(IEnumerable<T> collection)` constructor? Otherwise, what use is the `Stack<T>` if you can't access it?

Comment: You gotta have tried something that didn't work, right? What did you try and how did it not work?

Comment: I have added some code that I have got working with some similar code. I am just in need of some help with a different data type.

Comment: Generics are a *compile-time* tool, designed to help you catch type errors at compile time. Since you use reflection, the compiler cannot check your types and the advantages of using generics are moot. In that case, a simple `Stack<object>` might be the better and more readable solution.